# How to set the row names of a data frame passed on with the pipe %>% operator?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, magrittr

I have a data frame which I am `dcast`ing using the `reshape2` package, and I would like to remove the first column and have it become the row names of the data frame instead.

Original dataframe, before `dcast`:

```
> corner(df)

ID_full      gene cpm
1  S36-A1   DDX11L1   0
2  S36-A1    WASH7P   0
3  S36-A1 MIR1302-2   0
4  S36-A1   FAM138A   0
5  S36-A1     OR4F5   0
```

`pivot` function to dcast the table:

```
 library(reshape2)

 pivot <- function(x){
             castTable <- x %>% dcast(ID_full ~ gene, value.var="cpm")
             }
```

After `dcast`, wrapped in my `pivot` function:

```
> corner(df)

ID_full 1060P11.3 A1BG A1BG-AS1 A1CF
1  S36-A1         0    0        0    0
2 S36-A10         0    0        0    0
3 S36-A11         0    0        0    0
4 S36-A12         0    0        0    0
5  S36-A2         0    0        0    0
```

I'd like ID_full to become the rownames, and to cease existing as a column, piped after `dcasting`. I can do this in several lines, replacing the data frame each time, but I'd like to do it all using the `%>%` operator.

The best attempt I can think of would involve something like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% pivot(.) %>% with(., row.names=df[,1])
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions... this nuisance is driving me crazy!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for your answers:

This expression works nicely:

```
df <- df %>% pivot(.) %>% `rownames<-`(.[,1]) %>% select(-ID_full)

> corner(df)

        1060P11.3 A1BG A1BG-AS1 A1CF        A2M
S36-A1          0    0        0    0    0.00000
S36-A10         0    0        0    0    0.00000
S36-A11         0    0        0    0    0.00000
S36-A12         0    0        0    0    1.62189
S36-A2          0    0        0    0 1170.95000
```

Comment: `dput()` > console output. Where the @#$@# is `corner()` from?  `?rename` ; `?rownames`.

Comment: `?tibble::column_to_rownames`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

with the later version of `tibble`, a more elegant solution exists:

```
df <- df %>% pivot(.) %>% tibble::column_to_rownames('ID_full')
```

Importantly, it works also when the column to turn to the rowname is passed as a variable, which is super-convenient, when inside the function!

Answer (score 33):

will this do?

```
iris %>% `rownames<-`(seq_len(nrow(iris)))
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `magrittr` alias `set_rownames`:

```
df %>% set_rownames(.$ID_full)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4,k=c('a','b')) 
df %>% data.frame(row.names = 'k') # remove column k
df %>% data.frame(row.names = 3) # remove column k
df %>% data.frame(row.names = .$k) # keep column k
df %>% data.frame(row.names = .[[3]]) # keep column k
df %>% data.frame(row.names = c('A','B')) # use any other vector as rowname
```