# How can I remove the row names inserted into a pander table?

Tags: r, pander

I'm using the `knitr` package to produce some basic table. I'm displaying the first *n* rows of a table on one slide and the last *n* rows of the same table on the next slide. I'm using `head()` and `tail()` to get the first and last rows.

Using `head()` produces what I expect:

```
library(dplyr)
library(pander)

data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, 10), 
           b = sample(LETTERS, 10)) %>%
head(5) %>% 
pander()
```

Produces

```
-------
 a   b 
--- ---
 G   B 

 I   P 

 N   H 

 U   W 

 V   A 
-------
```

but

```
data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, 10), 
           b = sample(LETTERS, 10)) %>%
tail(5) %>% 
pander()
```

produces

```
----------------
 &nbsp;   a   b 
-------- --- ---
 **6**    Y   B 

 **7**    F   O 

 **8**    B   H 

 **9**    R   Y 

 **10**   W   X 
----------------
```

and I can't remove the row names from the final table.

[The top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018646/how-do-i-remove-row-names-when-using-pander-to-brew-a-report) suggests that Pander removes the row names from a table when they are `1:n` but here, they begin with 1, so they're not removed automatically.

How can I prevent the row numbers from being displayed? I've tried using `select()` as well as using the **UPDATE** from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518218/how-to-set-the-row-names-of-a-data-frame-passed-on-with-the-pipe-operator) to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the rownames to be displayed you could remove them using `rownames(df) <- NULL` (after the `tail`) but I don't know how to use this in the pipe.
One hack would be to convert to a tibble and then convert back to a data frame (because tibbles don't store rownames but you can't use `pander` on tibbles apparently):

```
data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, 10), 
           b = sample(LETTERS, 10)) %>%
  dplyr::as.tbl() %>%
  tail(5) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pander()
```

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out how to use `rownames(df) <- NULL` with the pipe operator either. Including `as.tbl()` and `as.data.frame()` works for now. There's gotta be a better way, though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to open an issue on the [github](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/115) account of `pander`

Another hack is using slice:

```
library(dplyr)
library(pander)

data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, 10), 
           b = sample(LETTERS, 10)) %>%
  slice(n()-5:n()) %>% 
  pander()
```

Comment: A more streamlined hack. [Issue opened](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/301).